# Why doesn't program prompt for additional answers

Tags: c

**Here's the question**

Why does the following program not prompt for additional answers, after it has prompted for the first?

**Here are some additional details**

(c) An Insurance company follows following rules to calculate premium.
(1) If a person’s health is excellent and the person is between 25 and 35 years of age and lives in a city and is a male then the premium is Rs. 4 per thousand and his policy amount cannot exceed Rs. 2 lakhs.
(2) If a person satisfies all the above conditions except that the sex is female then the premium is Rs. 3 per thousand and her policy amount cannot exceed Rs. 1 lakh.
(3) If a person’s health is poor and the person is between 25 and 35 years of age and lives in a village and is a male then the premium is Rs. 6 per thousand and his policy cannot exceed Rs. 10,000.
(4) In all other cases the person is not insured.
Write a program to output whether the person should be insured or not, his/her premium rate and maximum amount for which he/she can be insured.

**Here's my CODE**

```
/* pg 88 G-c
06/07/2012 6:14pm */

#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main() {
    char health,live,sex;
    int age,insured=0,policy=0,premium;

    printf("where is the person living? C or c for city OR V or v for village");
    scanf("%c",&live);
    printf("enter the health of the person: E or e for excellent OR P or p for poor");
    scanf("%c",&health);
    printf("what's the Sex of the person? M or m for Male OR F or f for Female");
    scanf("%c",&sex);
    printf("enter the age of the person");
    scanf("%d",&age);

    if((health=='E'||health=='e')&&(age>=25&&age<=35)&&(live=='C'||live=='c')&&(sex=='M'||sex=='m')) {
        insured=1;
        premium=4;
        policy=200000;
    }
    else if((health=='E'||health=='e')&&(age>=25&&age<=35)&&(live=='C'||live=='c')&&(sex=='F'||sex=='f')) {
        insured=1;
        premium=3;
        policy=100000;
    }
    else if((health=='P'||health=='p')&&(age>=25&&age<=35)&&(live=='V'||live=='v')&&(sex=='M'||sex=='m')) {
        insured=1;
        premium=6;
        policy=10000;
    }

    if(insured==1) {
        printf("the person is insured");
        printf("the premium of the person is %d Rs. per thousand",premium);
        printf("the policy cannot exceed Rs. %d", policy);
    }
    else
        printf("the person is not insured");
}
```

**Here's the Problem**
when the screen asks for the place where person live i enter C,c or V,v and when i press enter it displays the second question i.e. person's health and straight away asks the third question i.e. sex of the person.

it doesn't give me the place or option to enter the value for the 2nd question :(

i want to know why is this happening... please help me
thanks and regards
Saksham

Answer (score 5):

When you press enter, you also add a `\n` character, which your `scanf()` is happy to accept as the next input.  The easiest solution in your case, is to tell `scanf()` to read the next *non-whitespace* character. This can be done like:

```
scanf(" %c",&health); /* note the added space before %c! */
```

This space in the format will make `scanf()` eat any leading whitespace characters that it finds.

Comment: wow, amazing, it worked like a charm :)
thank you so much.

can you suggest me any books, that might help me overcome such basic problems?

Comment: `scanf()` is a really complex function, and honestly I prefer to avoid it in general. As far as books, I'd suggest the canonical K&R2: http://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Language-2nd-Ed/dp/0131103709 . This is a "must have" for any serious C programmer.

Comment: I find that I prefer `scanf("%c\n", &health);` in terms of visual recognition.

Comment: thanks FatalError, i tried a few more things so the answer that you gave if we don't follow that then the scanf would automatically store \n for the 2nd answer, right?

JAB, thanks for another way to solve the problem :)

YOU GUYS ROCK

Comment: You can also do something like `scanf("%c*%c", &health);`; the `*` makes it _discard_ what is specified next. Please someone correct me if I have done this wrong.